# Meteor - Return HTML Template via ajax

Tags: ajax, api, templates, meteor, handlebars.js

I would like to display a template generated in my Meteor app on another website.

I had hoped to use an ajax call in the website to fetch the relevant meteor template and data, but I am struggling.

the website makes the call as follows:

```
<body>
  <div id="result">
</div>
</body>

<script>
  $( "#result" ).load( "http://myMeteorApp/get_template" );
</script>
```

In the Meteor app I have tried to return the template using iron-router:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('get_template', {
    where: 'server',
    path: 'get_template',   
    action: function () {
      return 'get_template'
    }
})
```

The template 'get_template.html' is in the 'private' folder.

```
<template name="get_template">    
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>      
      <th>Mobile</th>          
    </tr>
    {{#each members}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
      <td>{{mobile}}</td>          
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
```

This does not work and I have a feeling I am barking up the wrong tree.

Maybe I ought to be using an iframe?  But I prefer for the Meteor app to behave like an API and simply return the template.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#server-side-routing:

> Server action functions (RouteControllers) have different properties
>   and methods available. Namely, there is no rendering on the server
>   yet.

Also, even if that was working there is a lot missing in your javascript:

- You don't seem to specify anywhere the data to use in the template
- The action function returns a string. What is this supposed to do?

I think your best bet is to use a server-side template engine such as [meteor-handlebars-server](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server) and just manually render the template:

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('serverFile', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/get_template/:templatename',

    action: function () {
      var templatename = this.params.templatename;
      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      this.response.end(Handlebars.templates[templatename]({members: []}));
    }
  });
});
```

Inserting the data in the `members` field of the supplied object.

Comment: Yep, so RTFM!  I wonder if 1.0 and new branches of iron-router will include server-side routing?